# Multiple "ajax loading" icons appear on repeated slow requests

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

Clicking on the close link on a question triggers an ajax request, and whilst waiting for the response a small loader animation is displayed next to the link.  If that request is slow for any reason, and you press the link multiple times "to hurry things along", you end up with multiple images:

[image: multiple loader images]

Comment: @Frédéric Yeah that's the same, thanks!

Comment: That duplicate is now deleted. But - known issue and we won't fix it. It does no harm and there is a simple resolution - **don't do that**.

Comment: @Oded "But doctor, it hurts when I..." - fair enough :)

Comment: Heh. Clicked the close link in the picture to see if I could reproduce :)

Comment: "Just avoid holding it in that way."

Comment: @meskobalazs don't point the knife at your chest and you'll be alright

Comment: Doing it with flag gets you "You may only open the flag dialog every three seconds"

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC You get the same thing with close normally too.  It was only when the connection was _very_ bad.

Comment: it may be fixed by an simple if condition