# How did this duplicate target question get deleted?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

Here on Meta, I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306590/multiple-ajax-loading-icons-appear-on-repeated-slow-requests) (now reopened since I asked this), which is closed as duplicate of [this (deleted) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303261/clicking-on-close-multiple-times-causes-multiple-ellipses).

However, according to [this Q&A on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221619/auto-flag-duplicates-of-deleted-questions-for-reopening-deletion), this is not supposed to happen - it should not be possible to delete questions which are used as duplicate targets.

What's going on here?

Comment: For reference, it was deleted by the clean-up script: deleted by Community♦ Jan 16 at 1:29 (RemoveDeadQuestions)

Comment: In that case, the Roomba should be fixed so that it doesn't delete questions which are used as duplicate targets..

Comment: I might be the user that caused it to be deleted. I just notice I down voted that question which made it eligible for the Roomba in the first place. Me is bad.

Comment: Undeleted now, by the powah of meta!

Comment: Hmm.. I always thought that only questions with answers could serve as dupe targets. What's the point in that dupe target if there is no proposed solution there?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: The same point that if it had answers, ensuring that all collected answers end up in one place. SO was primarily built to solve the issue of nuggets of knowledge pertaining to a question being scattered all over the place, any time you have multiple open similar questions on SO, you are once again poised to scatter knowledge instead of consolidating all those nuggets in a single place (and you are also raising the maintenance cost: see copy/paste programming).

Comment: @DavidArenburg I believe the "must have answers" rule doesn't apply on meta sites - it wouldn't make sense to have duplicate bugs and feature requests, and those usually don't get an answer until they're in fixed / implemented.

Comment: @MatthieuM. but you can't close a dupe with a dupe target that has no answers on SO (except for Meta it seems) so I don't see what you trying to say. I know that dupes should be closed. I'm #1 on [tag:r] with hammering dupes all time. But it has nothing to do with what I was saying.